# Dynamic SQL errors out on 2nd reference to non-existing database, but not on the 1st – SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a procedure that transfers archive data from 2 tables to monthly databases. A new monthly database is created every month.

Because the data transfer process is automated, dynamic SQL is used to reference a monthly database. The procedure looks for the monthly database for the current month and for the previous month.

If the previous month database is not present on the instance for any reason, any second reference to it causes the procedure to error out. However, a single reference to a non-existing database does not cause the procedure to error out.

This issue can be fixed by placing the below line of code before 2nd reference to the non-existing database:

```
If Exists (select top 1 1 from sys.databases where name = ''' + @PreviousMonthDatabase + ''')
```

I'm trying to understand what causes the error out for only the second appearance of a reference to non-existing objects in dynamic SQL.

Below is pseudo code for the dynamic SQL:

```
If @CurrentMonthRows1 Is Not Null
     BEGIN   
 Transfer some data into @CurrentMonthDatabase for table 1
     END

If @PreviousMonthRows1 Is Not Null
     BEGIN   
 Transfer some data into @PreviousMonthDatabase for table 1 (first reference to non existing DB – no error raised)
     END

If @CurrentMonthRows2 Is Not Null
     BEGIN   
 Transfer some data into @CurrentMonthDatabase for table 2 
     END

If @PreviousMonthRows2 Is Not Null
     BEGIN   
 Transfer some data into @PreviousMonthDatabase for table 2 (second reference to non existing DB – an error is raised)
     END
```

Comment: which error exactly and the pseudo code is much too short,we also don't now the design not your tables

Comment: It's not reproducible, the proc with definition: create proc sp_test1
as 
begin
exec(
   'select *
    from db.dbo.test1')
exec(
   'select *
    from db.dbo.test2')
end causes 2 errors and not just the second:

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'db.dbo.test1'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'db.dbo.test2'.

Comment: Also `WHERE name = ''' + @PreviousMonthDatabase + '''` is almost certainly intended to be `WHERE name = @PreviousMonthDatabase` I doubt your database is really `' + SomeName + '`

Comment: @Charlieface - I think the OP has just copied a portion of their dynamic SQL (out of context of the entire statement), so it would likely end up being valid

Comment: @Craig Then there is probably bad SQL injection going on. We need a [mcve] either way.

Comment: Okay so I resolved the issue. Turns out the first reference to the non-existing database doesn't error out because the IF PreviousMonthRows1 Is Not Null returns as false(ie, PreviousMonthRows1 variable is null and there are no rows for the previous month) , and is skipped as a result. This means you can reference non-existing objects in IF clauses (and maybe other invalid code) without causing an error. Cool!